# convert array to string in $project (aggregate)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i use $project operation to specify the inclusion of fields i have this code:

```
[{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'users',
        'localField': 'owner',
        'foreignField': 'id'
        'as': 'user'
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'userName': '$user.username',
        'userId': '$user.id'
    }
}]
```

i have the result below:

```
[
    {
        "userName": [
            "jscode"
        ],
        "userId": [
            "5d1888d60c627764aabd8b1e"
        ]
    }
]
```

i need to convert **userId** and **userName** results from **array** to **string**  like this:

```
[
    {
        "userName": "jscode" ,
        "userId": "5d1888d60c627764aabd8b1e"
    }
]
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

```
{
  "$project": {
    "userName": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$user.username", 0] },
    "userId": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$user.id", 0] }
  }
}
```

Or Using [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
[
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "owner",
    "foreignField": "id",
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$user" },
  { "$project": {
    "userName": "$user.username",
    "userId": "$user.id"
  }}
]
```

Actually [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) always returns the new field in form of array. So to pick the field from that array you either need to use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) or can [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to pick the 0th element.